# Google Earth: Disable flyToView on runtime

Tags: javascript, google-earth

I'm currently making an application where I use google earth to display a path. This path will be updated on a regular basis, and I've used a network link to connect the google earth to a KML file.

The problem is that every time google earth recieves an update from the KML it resets the view. I would like to disable this feature, but still be able to "fly" to a specific location on startup.

I've tried using setFlyToView(false) on the network link, but this results in no flying at all. What I would like, is for google earth to fly to the location of the placemark at start, and then when it updates -from the KML file through the network link- it doesn't fly anywhere.

Is there a way to access and change options when google earth is already running? If it's possible I could then use the setFlyToView(true) at initialization and then setFlyToView(false) when google earth has already changed the view to where I want to be, thereby disabling the updating of the view, but not the initial view position.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What JavaScript API are you using to load/manipulate the KML? If javascript is loading the KML file - is flyToView set to 1 as a child element of the NetworkLink in the KML file (note element names are case-sensitive) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is the behavior if you have flyToView set 1 in the NetworkLink. Check that the flyToView element is child of the NetworkLink not the Link. Possibly the KML being generated by the JavaScript API you're using is not setting the flyToView correctly or it isn't supported.

```
<Document>
  <visibility>1</visibility>
  <NetworkLink>
    <name>NE US Radar</name>
    <refreshVisibility>1</refreshVisibility>
    <flyToView>1</flyToView>
    <Link>...</Link>
  </NetworkLink>
</Document>
```

Also, you may want to override default view with a LookAt or Camera element added to the NetworkLink to fly.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm currently creating the network link in the JavaScript and setting the flyToView to 0. And just like you suggested I use the lookAt instead. This results in what I wanted to do. Now the problem will be getting the correct Long/Lat since it's dynamic and was handled automatically by the flyToView.